# Replace a row with several rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace a row of a dataframe with several lines from a dict that only contains a few keys:

```
     A   B   C   D
0   45  88  44  92
1   62  34   2  86
2   85  65  11  31
3   74  43  42  56
4   90  38  34  93
5    0  94  45  10
6   58  23  23  60
```

with `d = {'A':[13,2,3], 'D':[3,2,3]}` from line `line_to_replace` (let say 2).

In order to obtain:

```
     A   B   C   D
0   45  88  44  92
1   62  34   2  86
2   13  65   3  31
2_1  2  None None 2
2_2  3  None None 3
3   74  43  42  56
4   90  38  34  93
5    0  94  45  10
6   58  23  23  60
```

I tried:

```
df.loc[line_to_replace] = pd.Series(d)
```

But got:

```
ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value
```

## The original problem

I have [a dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11mj8Z8ijaguxJCsQBA2QO2NV4rowV1C5/view?usp=sharing) with rows of which I want to change a few lines for several lines at a time and [another, Pickle](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15boZG27t_DL8SEMn-ObyRMqKE3bCFR1I/view?usp=sharing), which contains the information to build the lines that will update the old ones. Each time an old line will be transformed into several new lines (I specify this because I don't know how to do it).

These lines are only the titles of grid of questions like the following:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I want to insert them in the original dataframe, instead of the lines where they match in the 'Questions' column, as rows as in the dataframe:

```
import pickle

qa = pd.read_pickle(r'Python/interns.p')
df = pd.read_csv("QuestionBank.csv")

def isGrid(dic):
    d_answers = dic['answers']
    try:
        answers = d_answers[2]
        if len(answers) > 1:
            # find the line in df and replace the line where it matches by the lines
            update_lines(dic, df)
    except TypeError:
        print("truc")
        
def update_lines(dic, df):
    '''find the line in df and replace the line where it matches by the new lines'''
    print("dic: ", dic)
    line_to_replace = df.index[df['Questions'] == dic['question']].tolist() # might be several rows and maybe they aren't all to replace
    # replace this row and the following by the following dataframe
    questions = reduce(lambda a,b: a + b,[data['answers'][2][x][3] for x in range(len(data['answers'][2]))])
    print("dic", dic)
    ind_answers = dic["answers"][2][0][1]
    answers = []
    for i in range(len(ind_answers)):
        answers.append(reduce(lambda a,b: a+b,[ind_answers[i] for x in range(len(questions))]))
    dict_replacing = {"Questions": questions,"Answer_1":answers[0],"Answer_2":answers[1],"Answer_3":answers[2],"Answer_4":answers[3],"Answer_5":answers[4]}
    df.loc[line_to_replace] = pd.Series(dict_replacing) # bad idea, I lose the information about the keys of where to insert
```

But got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1206-ca5f285affa4> in <module>
      2     for dic in sets:
      3         if 'https' not in dic:
----> 4             isGrid(dic)

<ipython-input-1205-080501d6bc00> in isGrid(dic)
     10         if len(answers) > 1:
     11             # find the line in df and replace the line where it matches by the lines
---> 12             update_lines(dic, df)
     13     except TypeError:
     14         print("truc")

<ipython-input-1205-080501d6bc00> in update_lines(dic, df)
     26         answers.append(reduce(lambda a,b: a+b,[ind_answers[i] for x in range(len(questions))]))
     27     dict_replacing = {"Questions": questions,"Answer_1":answers[0],"Answer_2":answers[1],"Answer_3":answers[2],"Answer_4":answers[3],"Answer_5":answers[4]}
---> 28     df.loc[line_to_replace] = pd.Series(dict_replacing) # bad idea, I lose the information about the keys of where to insert

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    669             key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
    670         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
--> 671         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    672 
    673     def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
   1017                     if len(labels) != len(value):
   1018                         raise ValueError(
-> 1019                             "Must have equal len keys and value "
   1020                             "when setting with an iterable"
   1021                         )

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Comment: 1. We can't view those image, they are private. 2. It is better to copy your dataframe (and everything else) inline and not paste an image

Comment: So you need replace by lists? In each matched cell is list?

Comment: @jezrael I need to replace the data of line x with len(items in d that should be all the same) lines, containing d. I've just added the expected output, might be easier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to change your solution with append floats instead strings for correct ordering in new `DataFrame`, basically use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with new `DataFrame` by dictioanry with new index names by `line_to_replace`:

```
d = {'A':[13,2,3], 'D':[3,2,3]}

line_to_replace = 2
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
df1.index = df1.index / 10 + line_to_replace

df = df1.combine_first(df)
print (df)
        A     B     C     D
0.0  45.0  88.0  44.0  92.0
1.0  62.0  34.0   2.0  86.0
2.0  13.0  65.0  11.0   3.0
2.1   2.0   NaN   NaN   2.0
2.2   3.0   NaN   NaN   3.0
3.0  74.0  43.0  42.0  56.0
4.0  90.0  38.0  34.0  93.0
5.0   0.0  94.0  45.0  10.0
6.0  58.0  23.0  23.0  60.0
```