# Replace dataframe row with partial dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I want to replace a row of a dataframe with a dict that only contains a few keys:

```
     A   B   C   D
0   45  88  44  92
1   62  34   2  86
2   85  65  11  31
3   74  43  42  56
4   90  38  34  93
5    0  94  45  10
6   58  23  23  60
```

with `d = {'A':13, 'D':3}`

I tried:

```
df.loc[line_to_replace] = pd.Series(d)
```

But got:

```
---> 26     df.loc[line_to_replace] = pd.Series(dict_replacing) # bad idea, I lose the information about the keys of where to insert

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    669             key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
    670         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
--> 671         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    672 
    673     def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
   1017                     if len(labels) != len(value):
   1018                         raise ValueError(
-> 1019                             "Must have equal len keys and value "
   1020                             "when setting with an iterable"
   1021                         )

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

## Update

With the actual dataframe I was trying to update I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1215-ca5f285affa4> in <module>
      2     for dic in sets:
      3         if 'https' not in dic:
----> 4             isGrid(dic)

<ipython-input-1214-3f69d41d4a8a> in isGrid(dic)
     10         if len(answers) > 1:
     11             # find the line in df and replace the line where it matches by the lines
---> 12             update_lines(dic, df)
     13     except TypeError:
     14         print("truc")

<ipython-input-1214-3f69d41d4a8a> in update_lines(dic, df)
     24         answers.append(reduce(lambda a,b: a+b,[ind_answers[i] for x in range(len(questions))]))
     25     dict_replacing = {"Questions": questions,"Answer0":answers[0],"Answer1":answers[1],"Answer2":answers[2],"Answer3":answers[3],"Answer4":answers[4]}
---> 26     df.loc[line_to_replace, dict_replacing.keys()] = dict_replacing.values()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    669             key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
    670         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
--> 671         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    672 
    673     def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
   1022 
   1023                     for item, v in zip(labels, value):
-> 1024                         setter(item, v)
   1025             else:
   1026 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in setter(item, v)
    960                     s._consolidate_inplace()
    961                     s = s.copy()
--> 962                     s._data = s._data.setitem(indexer=pi, value=v)
    963                     s._maybe_update_cacher(clear=True)
    964 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in setitem(self, **kwargs)
    559 
    560     def setitem(self, **kwargs):
--> 561         return self.apply("setitem", **kwargs)
    562 
    563     def putmask(self, **kwargs):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in apply(self, f, filter, **kwargs)
    440                 applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    441             else:
--> 442                 applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    443             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    444 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in setitem(self, indexer, value)
    876 
    877         # length checking
--> 878         check_setitem_lengths(indexer, value, values)
    879         exact_match = (
    880             len(arr_value.shape)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexers.py in check_setitem_lengths(indexer, value, values)
    113             ):
    114                 raise ValueError(
--> 115                     "cannot set using a list-like indexer "
    116                     "with a different length than the value"
    117                 )

ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value
```

Here is the dataframe row I am trying to update:

```
line_to_replace [21]
df.loc[line_to_replace, list(dict_replacing.keys())]: 
                                           Questions         Answer0  \
21  What are new offers you are most interested in?  Not Interested   

                Answer1     Answer2            Answer3                 Answer4  
21  Somewhat Interested  Interested  Highly Interested  Very Highly Interested
```

And here is the dict containing the values that should update the dataframe:

```
 list(dict_replacing.values()): 
 [['The airline/company you fly with', 'The departure airport', 'Duration of flight/route', 'Price', 'Baggage policy', 'Environmental impacts'], ['Not Interested', 'Not Interested', 'Not Interested', 'Not Interested', 'Not Interested', 'Not Interested'], ['Somewhat Interested', 'Somewhat Interested', 'Somewhat Interested', 'Somewhat Interested', 'Somewhat Interested', 'Somewhat Interested'], ['Interested', 'Interested', 'Interested', 'Interested', 'Interested', 'Interested'], ['Highly Interested', 'Highly Interested', 'Highly Interested', 'Highly Interested', 'Highly Interested', 'Highly Interested'], ['Very Highly Interested', 'Very Highly Interested', 'Very Highly Interested', 'Very Highly Interested', 'Very Highly Interested', 'Very Highly Interested']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with set by list or scalar with keys for match columns names and set values of dictionary:

```
d = {'A':13, 'D':3}

line_to_replace = [1,5]
df.loc[line_to_replace, d.keys()] = d.values()
print (df)
    A   B   C   D
0  45  88  44  92
1  13  34   2   3
2  85  65  11  31
3  74  43  42  56
4  90  38  34  93
5  13  94  45   3
6  58  23  23  60
```

---

```
line_to_replace = 1
df.loc[line_to_replace, d.keys()] = d.values()
print (df)
    A   B   C   D
0  45  88  44  92
1  13  34   2   3
2  85  65  11  31
3  74  43  42  56
4  90  38  34  93
5   0  94  45  10
6  58  23  23  60
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) However I got an `ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value` with your method

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica - Can you test `df.loc[line_to_replace, list(d.keys())] = list(d.values())` ?

Comment: Yes, just gave the same ... :'(

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica - Is possible upgrade pandas ? Maybe version related problem.

Comment: Will try, my version is `Version: 1.0.3`

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica - I guess it is OK, I test duplicated index - working, not matched columns names, rows names and different errors. So no idea :(

Comment: I tried with your example and it worked, so thanks for that. I added the line I am actually replacing and the dict containing the values that should update the dataframe. Could you have a look if ever you have the time ? :)

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica - I think problem is with format of dictionary, it is different like in sample data.

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica - It is like `d = {'A':[13,2,3], 'D':[3,2,3]}`

Comment: I see what you mean! It's because I'm trying to [replace a row with several rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63050773/replace-a-row-with-several-rows)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df.loc[line_to_update, d.keys()] = d.values()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) However I got an `ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value` with your method

Comment: what's your `line_to_replace`?

Comment: An array with the matching lines. Now it is: `[21]`